# How to do outer join in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I need to outer join in rails

```
@recent_details = Property.joins(:space_amenities,:event_suitabilities,:purpose_suitabilities,:venue_categories).where(id: params[:id])
```

this active record gives me inner join. but i need outer join with this active record.

please help
Any help is appreciable

Comment: If you want to do left outer join, then use `includes` instead of `joins`.

Comment: @Pavan thanks :) working fine :)

Answer (score 3):

LEFT, RIGHT (OUTER) JOIN has all the same convention, when compiling JOINS, so basically You specify Your need:

```
@recent_details = Property.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN space_amenities ON space_amenities.property_id = properties.id").where(id: params[:id])
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use **includes** if you want LEFT OUTER joins or you can add manual joins like:

```
@recent_details = Property.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN space_amenities ON space_amenities.property_id = properties.id ").where(id: params[:id])
```

By this types of joins you can add any types of the joins like RIGHT outer etc..

Answer (score 1):

you can use the method [left_joins](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/left_joins):

```rb
@recent_details = Property.left_joins(:space_amenities)
```